# Multiple UIViews using a single datasource

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

How can I create a datasource that multiple views can access?

My current project has a `TabBarController` linking to multiple views that all need access to the same friendlist.

Currently, I am storing the datasource in a singleton class called `DataHolder`, for which the code is displayed below.

DataHolder.m

```
#import "DataHolder.h"
@interface DataHolder(){
    DataQuery *dataQuery;
    NSMutableArray *friendList;
}
@end
@implementation DataHolder
+(DataHolder*)sharedInstance{
    static DataHolder *_sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[DataHolder alloc]init];
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        NSLog(@"DataHolder init method called");
             dataQuery =[[DataQuery alloc]init];

    }
    return self;
}

-(NSMutableArray *)getFriendList{
    NSLog(@"Friend List from DataHolder %@", [dataQuery getFriendList]);
    return [dataQuery getFriendList];
}

-(void)logout{
    [friendList removeAllObjects];
}

@end
```

The problem that I am experiencing with it is that I can't have more than one view at a time hold the data. I am currently using an `NSMutableArray` property within each viewController and having them call `self.Array = [NSMutableArray ArrayWithArray:[DataHolder SharedInstance]GetFriendList]];` This does not always return any data at all, especially if another viewController has been called before. What I also find baffling is that some viewControllers will not display the data while another one has the data, and the next time I run the app its a different viewController that has the data.

EDIT: here is the `dataQuery` class that does the query and the `DataHolder` holds onto it.

DataQuery.m

```
@interface DataQuery(){

    NSMutableArray *friendsToAccept;
    //NSMutableArray *friendsList;
    int *count;
}

@end
@implementation DataQuery

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self){
        self.friendsList = [NSMutableArray new];
        //[self.friendsList mutableArrayValueForKey:@"friendsArray"];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getFriendList) name:@"friendList" object:nil];
        self.currentUser = [[CurrentUser sharedInstance]getCurrentUser];

        [self friendListQueryWithDataSource:self.friendsList];
        //[self checkForFriends];

    }
    return self;
}
-(NSMutableArray *)getFriendList{
    return self.friendsList;
}

-(void)friendListQueryWithDataSource:(NSMutableArray*)datasource{
    PFRelation *friendRelation = [self.currentUser relationForKey:@"friendRelation"];
    PFQuery *acceptedQuery = [friendRelation query];
    acceptedQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;


        [acceptedQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (error){
                NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }else{
                self.friendsList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:objects];
                NSLog(@"Friend List from DataQuery %@", self.friendsList);
            }
        }];


}
```

Here is how the view Controllers are both setup to display the data

```
#import "ConnectionTableViewController.h"


@interface ConnectionTableViewController (){
    DataHolder  *dataHolder;
}

@end

@implementation ConnectionTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.pending = [NSArray new];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.pending);
    self.friendList = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("word", NULL);
    self.friendList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[DataHolder sharedInstance] getFriendList]];


      [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"friendList"]) {
        for (PFUser *user in [[DataHolder sharedInstance]getFriendList]){
            [self.friendList addObject:user];
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

}
```

Comment: is `getFriendList` asynchronous?

Comment: No, getFriedList as it stands in the code from DataHolder is not using asynchronous processes, nor is the ViewController getting an asynchronous instance. Overall, I don't think they are asynchronous they are synchronous.

Comment: try moving the declaration of `_sharedInstance` out of the method. Move it up to the other ivars.

Comment: Doesn't really work, gives me a lot of errors when setting the sharedInstance.

Comment: I didn't mean to actually make it an ivar. It's a static variable. It needs to be outside the brackets.

Comment: Moving it out of the method into the iVar section is where the errors are coming form

Comment: Don't put it in the ivar section. Put it outside of the brackets, inside the implementation.

Comment: Hmmmm, I tried doing that and still getting an error, perhaps you could post an answer showing what you are trying to do?

Comment: I just tested your code manually and it works. The problem is likely not in the code you've shared.

Comment: Edited to show more code.

Comment: `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` should call super, and needs to use the context pointer. Where are you starting and stopping the KVO observations?

Comment: The data source is a core objective-c concept, what you have here appears to be an array holding model data rather than a data source. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Comment: KVO starts within  in the DataQuarry class, and is called [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(getFriendList) name:@"friendList" object:nil];. Next, each view controller has a method called -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    self.friendList = [[DataHolder sharedInstance]getFriendList];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"ConnectionTableView data updated");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSNotificationCenter to get notified when the data has finished downloading. It looks to me that you are using Parse as a backend.

Answer (score 0):

`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` is an asynchronous method! You will not have any data in friendList until it finishes.

Try making `getFriendList` asynchronous.

```
- (void)getFriendListWithCallback:(CallbackBlock)callback {
    //...
    if (self.friendsList.count == 0) {
        [acceptedQuary findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (error){
                self.friendsList = @[];
                NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

            } else {
                self.friendsList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:objects];
                NSLog(@"Friend List from DataQuary %@", self.friendsList);
            }
            if (callback) callback(self.friendsList);
        }];
    } else {
        if (callback) callback(self.friendsList);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is true, which is why in each viewController I have placed -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context to reload the tableView data. This however, does not solve the display problem. I wonder if there is a better method for observation to reload the tableView data.

Comment: The solution is to make your `getFriendList` method asynchronous.

Comment: getFriendList in the dataHolder class? How would asynchronicity solve the problem?

Comment: You are trying to use an asynchronous in a synchronous way. The solution you're using is KVO which is completely terrible. Use callback blocks.